# SMTP、特定のメールだけ「送信済みになるのに相手に届かない」のはなぜ？

Tags: linux, centos, mail

CentOSでMediawikiを運用中。

ブラウザでMediawiki(`http://wiki.example.com`)にアクセス、
メールアドレスを登録すると、一般ユーザーがwikiに書き込みができるようなシステムです。

---

システム: `admin@outlook.jp`

ユーザー1: `user1@yahoo.co.jp`
ユーザー2: `user2@na-cat.com`
（＠よりも前の部分はダミー、ドメイン名は実際のもの）

---

アカウント作成時、パスワードリセット時などに、Mediawikiのシステム(`admin@outlook.jp`)からユーザーにメールが自動送信されます。

アカウント作成時は、`メールアドレスの確認`という件名のメールが送信されます。
`ユーザー1`と`ユーザー2`、2つのユーザーを作成し、どちらも`メールアドレスの確認`を受信できています。

パスワードリセット時は、`アカウントの詳細`という件名のメールが送信されます。
`ユーザー1`と`ユーザー2`、2つのユーザーで試しましたが、どちらも`アカウントの詳細`を受信できませんでした。

https://outlook.live.com/
上記サイトへ`admin@outlook.jp`でログインし、送信済みボックスを確認しました。
`アカウントの詳細`のメールが送信済みになっています。
`ユーザー1`宛てと`ユーザー2`宛ての2通あります。

送信済みなのに、相手にメールが届かないのはなぜ？

---

メールがまったく届かないのならばMediawikiのSMTP設定が間違っている可能性が高い。
しかし、`メールアドレスの確認`の方のメールは、ユーザー側で受信できているので、SMTPの設定ミスではないと思われる。

迷惑メールに振り分けられているのかと思ったが、迷惑メールフォルダには該当メールはなし。

`ユーザー1`は`ヤフーメール`、`ユーザー2`は`捨てメアド`というメールサービスを利用している。

`メールアドレスの確認`は、迷惑メールに分類されないが、
`アカウントの詳細`の方だけ迷惑メールに分類されるという挙動はあり得るかもしれないが、
`ヤフーメール`と`捨てメアド`でまったく同じ挙動というのは不自然か？

違うメールサービスでも同じフィルタリングエンジンを使っていたらあり得るかも？

そもそも届いていないのか、
受信側のサーバーまでは届いているがユーザーに届く前に捨てられているのか
を切り分けたいが、どうすればいいのか分からず。

または、SMTP（outlook.live.com）側で何らかのフィルタがかかっていて、
送信したと見せかけて実際には送信していないというようなことがありえるのか？

---

まとめ

送信済みになっているのに、相手にメールが届かない場合、

・本当の本当に送信されているのか確認するには？
（送信済みボックスにメールが残っていたら、確実に送信されていると判断していいのか？）

・仮に迷惑メールに分類されているとしたら、迷惑メールに分類されたことを検知するには？
（`ヤフーメール`や`捨てメアド`のサービスでは、迷惑メールフォルダにすら表示されず、暗黙的にメールを消去していたりするかも？）
フリーのメールサービスで、自動で迷惑メールに分類せず、ノーガードでメールを受信できるようなものがあったら紹介してください。
そもそも届いていないのか、届いたけどフィルタリングされてユーザーからは見えないのかを切り分けたいです。

・「アカウント作成時のメール」は届くけど、「パスワードリセット時のメール」は届かない今回の現象について、その他アドバイスがあればお願い致します。

Comment: もう少し詳細な切り分けはできないでしょうか？質問に出てくる2つのドメインだけでなく、例えばgmail.comやicloud.comなどcomドメインである程度信頼性のおけるもの、またSMTPサーバがoutlook.jpであればoutlook.jpのドメインを持つ一般ユーザーを作ってそちらでもテストしてみて、どのドメインで送信できるか調べてみるのも良いかと思います。その結果を質問文にフィードバックしていただくと回答も付きやすくなるのではと思われます。差し支えなければメール本文（個人情報は伏せてください）も質問本文内に記載していただくと判断材料が増えて良いかと思います。

Comment: [Fix Outlook.com email sync issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-outlook-com-email-sync-issues-d39e3341-8d79-4bf1-b3c7-ded602233642) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: Mediawikiのシステム制限で、新規のアカウント作成ができません。
スパム対策で同一IPからのアカウント取得に制約があるようです。
公式のドキュメントを見てIPによる制限を解除したのですが、アカウント作成できないまま。
別のアドレスだとスパム判定されるのかは実験できず。
Mediawiki公式のドキュメントは不完全で使いづらさを感じるので、別のwikiエンジンに乗り換えようかと思います。

Answer (score 1):

相手に届かなかったメール、
件名、本文が同じものを同じ宛先に`https://outlook.live.com/`のWebメール上から送ってみました。

すると、`postmaster@outlook.com`から下記のようなメールが返ってきました。

`Remote Server returned '550 5.7.520 Message blocked because it contains content identified as spam. AS(4810)'`

というわけでスパム判定されていたので届かないということが判明。

Mediawikiのシステムから自動送信した時は、
・送信済みにはなる
・相手には届かない
・postmaster@outlook.comからメールがこない

Webメールから手動で送信した時は、
・送信済みにはなる
・相手には届かない
・postmaster@outlook.comからメールがくる

MediawikiからSMTPで送信した時に、postmaster@outlook.comからのメールが届かない原因は謎。